# SWIFT: Pass image from First View Controller to Second View Controller on button click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imageview, viewcontroller

im a Swift Beginner and I really need your help. Im working on my first IOS App. I'm working with multiple ViewControllers now and I want a User to fill out some information like Name, Date and to choose an image from his Gallery. After that, I want that he clicks on a button and the image has to be displayed in another ViewController. So my question now is, how can I create a new ImageView in my SecondViewController by clicking on this button in my FirstViewController.

This is the code I have used for creating an ImageView in the same ViewController, but now I need help to create an ImageView in another ViewController:

```
`let imageName = "barcelona-allgemeine-informationen-at"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var imageCons:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []

        view.addSubview(imageView)`
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow below steps:-

- Create ImageView in Second view controller using Storyboard or Programatically.
- Take UIImage variable in Second View controller.

  ```
  var image: UIImage?
  ```
- Pass captured image on First View controller by camera/Gallery to second view controller like this

  ```
  let viewController = SecondViewController(nibName:"SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
  viewController.image = pickedImage    
  navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
  ```
- In Second View Controller assign this image to your imageview

  ```
  imageView.image = image
  ```